# How To Use AND Statements With Java

Tags: java, int

I am writing some code that gives me a random string of numbers, they need to list under on integer but each number needs to be under a different math.random. For Instance, if two separate number are listed like 5 and 7, I don't want it to print 12, I would like it to print 57. But i don't want to use the System.out.println(Number1+Number2); way.

I have tried using the "&" Sign multiple ways but none seem to work.

```
   int Number1 = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((5) + 1));
   int Number2 = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((5) + 1));
   int Number3 = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((5) + 1));

   int finalcode=Number1&Number2&Number3;


    System.out.println("Promo Code Genorator:");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Your Promo Code Is: "+finalcode);
```

Instead, what happens is it picks the lowest number from there and prints them. Any Ideas?

Comment: Convert them to `String`'s and then concat them

Comment: How exactly would I do that GBlodgett?

Comment: `String finalCode = "" + Number1 + Number2 + Number3;`

Comment: What about when the leading numbers are 0? So you would get a string like `"012"` and as an int this is just 12. The leading zero is gone. Also as no one seems to have mentioned it `&` is the [logical and](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html) operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is suggested to use `String` if you want to combine a variety of numbers together.

You can write it like this:

```
int Number1 = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((5) + 1));
int Number2 = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((5) + 1));
int Number3 = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((5) + 1));

String finalcode = String.valueOf(Number1) + String.valueOf(Number2) + String.valueOf(Number3);

System.out.println("Promo Code Genorator:");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println("Your Promo Code Is: "+finalcode);
```

If you really need your final code to be a integer, you can use

```
int finalcode = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Number1) + String.valueOf(Number2) + String.valueOf(Number3));
```

in which `Integer.parseInt(String string)` takes in a string and return a integer.

FYI, if you want to convert it to long instead of integer, use `Long.parseLong(String string)`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm new to this site, so I apologize for the poor formatting...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I went ahead and fixed your formatting for you. [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/251362#251362) is a helpful guide on formatting. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks so much, GBlodgett!

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a nice problem to solve using streams and functional programming.

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class LazyNumbersTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int result = Integer.parseInt(
            Stream.generate(() -> (int)(Math.random() * ((5) + 1)))
                  .peek(System.out::println)
                  .limit(3)
                  .map(Object::toString)
                  .collect(Collectors.joining(""))
        );

        System.out.println("Promo Code Generator:");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Your Promo Code Is: " + result);        
    }
}
```

It's an infinite stream of random numbers, from which we pluck the first 3 and convert them to string, then join them together and convert to an integer.

If you want more or less numbers in the calculation, just change the number in `limit`. It's a shame I couldn't include the `parseInt` in the stream of fluent operations (without making it really ugly).